# Image Resolution is decrease wile downloading Image to local machine using Java code

Tags: java, image, image-processing

I am trying to download High resolution Image from URL using Java Code.
but after download to local machine, the resolution of image is decrease.
I am using below code to download, can anybody suggest me where I am making mistake.

```
String url = "https://s3.eu-central-1.amazonaws.com/euroc-inspect/processing/E1039585_TOP_3_1.jpg";
URL liveUrl = new URL(url);
BufferedImage bimg = ImageIO.read(liveUrl);
int width          = bimg.getWidth();
int height         = bimg.getHeight();
ImageIO.write(bimg, "jpg", new File("E:/img.jpg"));
System.out.println("Image Saved");
```

Comment: Note that you don't have to convert it to an image, you may simply download it like any binary file.

Comment: I tried your code and for me the image gets downloaded as is. Image is around 466KB and upon downloading also it is same. How are you concluding the saved image is having lower resolution?

Comment: @PushpeshKumarRajwanshi The Actual size of image is 2.04MB and Height x width is 5962 x 4148.

Comment: @dev23: Try opening the given url and inspect its size, it shows 466KB. May be the link of image is different that is 2MB

Answer (score 0):

Getting the exact same resolution:

2048x1425

[image]

**ImageDownloader.java**:

```
import java.net.URL;
import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;
import javax.imageio.ImageIO;
import java.io.File;

public class ImageDownloader {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception{
        if(args.length<2) {
            System.out.println("Usage: ImageDownloader <url> <localfilename>");
            System.exit(1);
        }

        String url = args[0] ;
        String targetFile = args[1];

        URL liveUrl = new URL(url);
        BufferedImage bimg = ImageIO.read(liveUrl);
        int width          = bimg.getWidth();
        int height         = bimg.getHeight();

        ImageIO.write(bimg, targetFile.substring(targetFile.indexOf(".")), new File(targetFile));
        System.out.printf("Image %s saved. (size: %dx%d)",targetFile, width, height);
    }
}
```

original image
[image]

Comment: Thank for reply, The Actual size of image is 2.04MB and Height x width is 5962 x 4148.

Comment: @dev23 as far as I can see it's not .. is there a different URL for a different size ?